# Python submodule in the same file as module

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

If I currently have a file that is importing:

```
from foo import f0
from foo.bar import f1
```

I can create a file `foo.py` with a function `f0` in it to satisfy the first import.

Is there any way to satisfy the second import from within that same file `foo.py`?

Answer (score 9):

I just wanted to do that same thing. I only found this question, without an actual answer. So, here's what I came up with as a solution:

```
import sys

def add_submodule(submod):
    name = submod.__name__
    sys.modules[__name__ + "." + name] = submod(name)


from types import ModuleType

class submod1(ModuleType):
    class foo:
        pass

class submod2(ModuleType):
    class bar:
        pass


add_submodule(submod1)
add_submodule(submod2)
```

In essence, you subclass `types.ModuleType` to define a module. You then add it manually to `sys.modules` below the namespace of the current module, as given by `__name__`.

---

This is a minimal solution. If one would want to move `add_submodule()` to a separate stand-alone module for re-usability, it would have to be expanded a bit:
One could not simply use `__name__` as this would be the namespace where `add_submodule()` was defined in. This should work instead:

In the separate module:

```
def add_submodule(submod, parentname):
    name = submod.__name__
    sys.modules[parentname + "." + name] = submod(name)
```

In the actual module:

```
add_submodule(submod1, __name__)
add_submodule(submod2, __name__)
```

I fear there's no nicer way of getting the parent's name into the function, though.

---

Both cases can now be used like so:

> In [1]: import submodtest.submod1 as sm1
>
> In [2]: import submodtest.submod2 as sm2
>
> In [3]: sm1. [TAB]
>
> sm1.foo  sm1.mro
>
> In [3]: sm2. [TAB]
>
> sm2.bar  sm2.mro

---

EDIT: Pushed the above full example to [my Github](https://github.com/NichtJens/aSuMo).

Answer (score -4):

Create a directory called foo

- Within this directory, have a file called `__init__.py`
- This effectively creates a module called foo
- In this file, store the functions you want bundled with foo

Create a subdirectory of foo, called bar.

- Within this directory, have a file called `__init__.py`
- This effectively creates a sub module foo.bar
- In this file, store the functions you want bundled with foo.bar

Comment: This does not answer the question; my question is for a solution solely using a file called `foo.py`. A less restricted version of the problem requires using `foo.py, but allows that file to import from other files

Comment: Maybe it's worth pointing out, why I wanted to do this: I'm using a given library (actually compiled C++ code) that talks with hardware that I don't always have access to. Therefore, I wanted to mock up some drop-in replacement for working on the code. However, I wanted this to be a single file so I don't pollute my working directory too much. I don't know though if this is anything like what @Alex had in mind...

Answer (score -5):

No, you should create a directory named foo as a package.

Click [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages) to read official documentation about `The import system`